# delay loading of a silverlight page

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

How would i go about delaying the total load of a SilverLight Page? I take a parameter out of the querystring on the page load of a Silverlight web page, and then send it to a web service boolean function to process. The result of the return value is used to determine whether to fully load and display the page, or direct to another page. The system works pretty much fine, however when the result from the web service returns, even if it is decided that i need to navigate away to another page, it still displays the initial page for a very short time. How can I stop this brief showing of the initial page?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/CodeOptimizationTechnique.aspx

The point is that you must not do anything until you receive the data back from the webserice. When you receive it only when you can send the user to the right side, and remember also to consider that maybe you do not get a response from the server sometimes.